# FactomineR : Clusters of the supplementary individuals

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I'm performing a Hierarchical Clustering Analysis using FactomineR on an MCA. All runs perfectly well.

I have put some supplementary individuals in my MCA. But I want to know in which clusters they will be. For the moment I only have the results on the active individuals (with *res.hcpc$data.clust* or *res.hcpc$call$X*)

Do you know how it could be possible to know in which cluster all of the supplementary individuals are ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no equivalent of supplementary individuals in clustering. However, you can perform the clustering on the coordinates of both active and supplementary rows, like this (assuming `res.mca` holds your `MCA` object)

```
r <- rbind(res.mca$ind$coord,
           res.mca$ind.sup$coord)
res.hclust <- hclust(dist(r),method="ward.D")
```

Comment: I have a similar question its related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72958698/adding-group-information-to-3d-plot-in-factoextra is there a simple way of plotting?